# GVR reticle pointer lossing its shader at runtime on loading scene from asset bundle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I am using google VR for android using Unity3d 2017.3.1f1, I have put my scene into an asset bundle and loading it at runtime. On loading the scene the GVRReticlePointer object seems to loose it shader on ReticlePointer material. The Reticle Pointer appear pink and does not work. [image: The reticle pointer appears pink and does work]

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug, shaders and asset bundles are not friends.
https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208380753-Shaders-are-pink-when-loaded-from-an-AssetBundle

The only workarround is to have the shader on the base project, and when you load the material, find the shader via code:

material.shader = Shader yourShader;

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-shader.html

Comment: I tried this also by providing shader at runtime using script but still the problem persists. I tried by finding GoogleVR/Reticle shader. I also included the shader in graphics settings.